# Get user likes facebook

Tags: facebook

I have problem when get the list pages, which facebook user liked. I have found documents about user likes at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/

But I can not apply for other user id without my user ID.
All time, It return empty.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=730276762%2Flikes&version=v2.6

Could you please give me suggestion for my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not just query information about other users willy-nilly.

Each user that you want to get this data from, has to login to your app, and grant it the necessary permission.

(And Facebook has to review your app’s use of that permission, before you can ask normal users for it. For testing, you can ask it of any user that has a role in the app.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I have send ticket to facebook. About the conflict at document. Because when facebook type {user_id}/likes, it means all user ID should be applicable. Because currently, It's lile /me/likes

Comment: `me` is just an alias/shortcut, referring to the user that the access token belongs to. Whether you use `/me/likes` or `/{my_actual_user_id}/likes`, does not make a difference in that regard; both work – but only under the condition, that this specific user has granted your app permission to read their likes.